# How can I copy a Region of Interest into an image in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, image-processing

**The Problem:**

Using C#, I want to select an area from a WPF Image control, and store that region in another Image control.

**Input:**

I have an Image control in WPF who's Source is set to a beautiful .PNG picture. I also have a rectangle- my *region of interest*- selected on it. So, I've got the top-left corner coordinates of the rectangle (with respect to the Image control), and its height/width.

**Desired Output:**

How can I use this information to take what's in my ROI (Region of Interest) and put it into another Image control?

**Relevant Code (setting Image.Source):**

`imgContainer.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(openFileDialog.FileName));`

**What I've tried so far:**

I used Emgu CV (an openCV wrapper for C#) to instantiate a Mat(sourceImage, RegionOfInterest) which was supposed to return another Mat with the specified region of interest, but between the conversions from Bitmap, to Mat, to ImageSource, etc, it became convoluted and shakily estimated. Also, an added *twist*- I've got zooming and panning implemented on my image as well (within a Canvas), so as I move/resize the original image, the ROI moves/resizes with it as well.

Comment: Take a look at [CroppedBitmap](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.croppedbitmap(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Perfect fix. Thanks @Clemens